# Xcode: NSString to NSUrl conversion issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsurl

I am having a strange issue while converting a NSString to NSUrl. Actually I have a method which takes NSString as a parameter and then converts that to NSUrl and then I use that URL to download a file.

When I call this method through my code by passing a url as string, the following line returns nil.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

But when I hard-code the string within same method, and then I convert the string to NSUrl, I get a proper URL. I don't know why this is happening. Can someone comment on this behaviour and suggest me some way to cope this issue?

```
//NSString *urlString = @"http://someimage.png"; // works that way but not when I send this urlstring as parameter of method
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSLog(@"Url after conversion %@", url);
```

Comment: May be the String u are passing to your method is not a proper url. Print the url using NSLog() before trying to convert it to NSURL in ur method

Comment: Can you add your method and it's call?

Comment: It's not clear where your urlString parameter comes from.

Comment: What you say doesn't make sense. We need to see your actual function and the code that's calling it. The devil is in the details.

Comment: For example, the first line, if uncommented, cannot work, because it doesn't compile.

Comment: Im guessing the urlstring is brazzers.com so he cannot reveal it. :D

Comment: `urlString` is it really a `NSString`? From where did you get it? Could it be because you parsed it wrong? Do it has extra ( or { ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for your answers. I finally have fixed the issue and the issue was in the URL string I was passing as a parameter. It had some extra "" at the ends which were not showing up in the NSLog as it was a normal string, but when I removed those "" from the url string and then converted it to NSURL, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

use as

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"http://someimage.png"]];
NSLog(@"Url after conversion %@", url);
```